# Как изменить отображение wx.Panel при его пересоздании?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, wxpython

В общем ситуация такая: я создаю окно с панелью, туда добавляю сайзеры с контентом и мне нужно, чтобы контент менялся при нажатии кнопки в меню.

Я ничего лучше не придумал, кроме как удалять исходную панель и пересоздать ее с новым контентом, но проблема в том, что при пересоздании панели контент нормально отображается только тогда, когда я меняю размер окна.

Я пробовал не пересоздавать панель, а создать новый сайзер и заменить им "старый" с помощью `panel.SetSizer()`, но там получается так, что контент нового просто накладывается поверх старого.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать так, чтобы панель нормально отображалась при пересоздании или если можно посоветуйте как изменить содержимое без пересоздания панели.

**main.py**

```
import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, title='Some app')
        
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        open_item = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "Открыть")
        menubar.Append(fileMenu, "Файл")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onOpen, open_item)
        
        #main frame content
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        
        welcome_vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        
        greet_text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER, label = 'Добро пожаловать')
        greet_font = wx.Font(40, family = wx.FONTFAMILY_MODERN, style = 0, weight = 90, 
                      underline = False, faceName ="", encoding = wx.FONTENCODING_DEFAULT)
        greet_text.SetFont(greet_font)
        
        welcome_vbox.Add(greet_text, flag = wx.CENTER)
        
        self.panel.SetSizer(welcome_vbox)
          
    def onOpen(self, event):

        self.panel.Destroy()
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        df_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        
        text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER, label = 'Some action')
        df_box.Add(text, flag = wx.CENTER)
        self.panel.SetSizer(df_box)
        self.panel.Layout()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Попробуйте в конце метода `onOpen(self, event)` добавить две строки: `self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(df_box)` и `self.panel.Center()`

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, но Ваше решение, к сожалению тоже не подошло(( Панель растягивается по окну только тогда, когда меняешь его размер. Но задачу я уже решил немного другим способом: я удаляю из сайзера все элементы с помощью HIde и Remove и уже после этого добавляю новые элементы. "Колхоз", конечно, но на большее моих мозгов не хватило( Еще раз спасибо за ответ и правки